# How to push operators to the bottom of the IntelliSense popup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm currently creating a **small** vector-math library. I want to fully support operators by overloading them. Because I want to be able to do `float*Vector` as well as `Vector*float` I had to put the operators as free functions inside of the namespace (I would like to have all of them placed at the same place).

Now everytime I want to grab something from that namespace (one of the Vector types for example) all the **operators are also shown in the browser-tooltip** (no idea how it's actually called). That would be okay if they were at the bottom of the popup, but because of alphabetical ordering they are on top. I know about the `__INTELLISENSE__` macro, but of course this makes IntelliSense complain whenever I actually use the operators.

Now for my question:
**Is there a way to push them to the bottom of the popup or hide them completely?**   The last option would actually be preferred. I know it's not the best idea to hide features from IntelliSense.

If it matters, I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this out of the box, unfortunately. You'd have to write a custom add-in that filters the IntelliSense listing, and I'm not even sure that's possible. Your other option would be to make the operators friend functions of a class. That's what I like to do because it reduces their scope and makes them less annoying in IntelliSense listings. Doesn't get rid of them entirely, I'm afraid.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, that actually works. You might consider posting this as an answer so I can upvote and accept it.